# yii2 replacing dependancy of yii 1.x

Tags: yii2, cache-dependency

I want to replace the dependancy from yii 1.x to yii 2.x. I am using dependancy as follows:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT count(*) FROM category');
$categoryList = Category::model()->cache(CACHE_TIMEOUT,$dependency)->findAll( array("condition"=>"category_id = 6 || (category_id>13)") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DbDependency` for set dependency. And use like that:

```
$dep = new DbDependency();
$dep->sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM category';
$result = $db->cache(function ($db) {
    return Category::find()->where('category_id = 6 || (category_id>13)')->all();
}, CACHE_TIMEOUT, $dep);
```